# User SSH into folder but can nano into any upper folder?

Tags: linux, permissions, google-cloud-platform, ubuntu-18.04, google-app-engine

I did `useradd -s /bin/rbash -d /var/www/html/directory USRNAME`

and on ssh login with USRNAME (including ssh key), it goes to `directory` and cd doesnt go back. So that works... but

if they use `nano /var/www/html/.env` (before *directory*) it will say

```
Unable to create directory /var/www/html/directory/.local/share/nano/: Permission denied
It is required for saving/loading search history or cursor positions.

Press Enter to continue
```

If they press `enter` it will allow them to read **any** file with nano.. anywhere in the system!

Any help to only allow this user to **that specific directory only using google cloud**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rbash is not a secure method for restricting shell users. It only limits shell inputs and not filesystem access for executables. On a standard linux system there are plenty of tools accessible in the $PATH to work around those restrictions, not only nano.

Proper restricted access is done by creating a chroot environment or jail, but which also requires providing all needed executables and potentially even /dev, /sys, or /proc hardlinks.

You could modify $PATH to only include safe commands, but that's a minefield and essentially also requires you to create a separate collection of executables.

The error you're seeing is likely related to the user not being allowed to write to /var/www/html/directory, but is unrelated to the actual issue at hand.